# Unable to compile the scss file in foundation

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

i just installed foundation with sass and now i compiled the scss directory for the first time  and i've been given this error in the output css.

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
```

I used this command from ruby command prompt

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

This is the first time i am trying to use foundation with SASS.
Please tell me where am i doing wrong.
thanks.

The .rb file looks like this

```
    # Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Comment: what are you using to compile! Compass?

Comment: @nol no just ruby command line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell  your framework where to find Foundation files. For example, compass config.rb file contains line "add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss""

Comment: check my updated question. i added .js file which seems to be ok for path.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer you can simply copy foundation files from the ruby gem or git to your sass dir.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer clone this repo https://github.com/zurb/foundation and put stuff from their scss folder to yours. Create app.scss file with  `@import "settings";
@import "foundation";` and  compile it. Should work.

Comment: the package is really big. it downloads. it like i a on 20 percent and around 16 MB is already downloaded. can i downloaded the latest in zip from git reps. thanks.